# Factory_girl Issue while executing test cases

Tags: ruby, rspec, factory-bot, ruby-1.9.3, ruby-2.0

I am new to factory_girl gem. My Ruby gem have static clientid, session & host.

My Factory code is like

```
Factory.define  do
 factory :session do |f|
        f.clientid "clientid string"
        f.secret " secret string"
        f.host "host string"
    end
end
```

My Spec code is like

```
describe '#new' do
    it 'works' do
      result = Factory.build(clientid, secret, host)
      expect(result).not_to be_nil
    end
end
```

My spec_helper file is

```
require 'rspec'
require 'factory_girl'
$LOAD_PATH.unshift File.expand_path('../../lib', __FILE__)
require 'mydemogem'
```

I am trying to create one factory for that. But it gives me following error:

```
/spec/factories.rb:1:in `<top (required)>': uninitialized constant Factory (NameError)
```

I am not sure why I am getting this error. I followed all syntax, and still getting this issue.

Comment: Can you post your rspec_helper.rb file?

Comment: @surya i have updated my spec file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For newer versions of factory girl the constant is called `FactoryGirl` just change `Factory.build(clientid, secret, host)` to `FactoryGirl.build(clientid, secret, host)` and in `factories.rb` change `Factory.define` to `FactoryGirl.define`